# VisualStudio2017のデザインビューの仕組みについて

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

VidualStudio2017にて、あるXamlをデザインビューで表示しようとしたところ、「アサートに失敗しました」ポップアップが表示されました。
追ってみると、あるメソッドにてDebug.Assertをしている箇所にてエラーが起きているようです。
ただXamlを開いただけなのに、実際のロジックが走るものなのでしょうか。

Comment: 助けにならないかもしれませんが、こんな報告があります。[XAML designer using wrong path](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/136050/xaml-designer-using-wrong-path.html)

Comment: 今の質問内容だと、その件に関して経験・知識のある人しか答えられませんが、試せるサンプルそのものか、それらへのリンクが提示されれば、それを使って別の人が調べることが出来ると思われます。

Comment: 質問内容に情報が少なすぎました。ご指摘受け止めます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実際のロジックが走ります。

Xamlの場合、[`DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode`添付プロパティ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_DesignerProperties_IsInDesignMode)を使うことで、デザインモードで実行されているか判定できるため、これで処理を分岐することを検討してください。

WinFormsでも同様でこちらは[`Component.DesignMode`プロパティ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component.designmode?view=netframework-4.8)で判定できるようになっています。またASP.NETの場合、Webですから実行時にはHTMLが生成されるわけですが、こちらもデザインモードではそれ用に別途UI表示できるようになっています。この際も[`Control.DesignMode`プロパティ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.designmode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Control_DesignMode)で判定することになります。

Comment: デザインモードで実行されているかの判断プロパティがあるのですね。使用するかは検討します。ちなみに、製品コードにもDesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode添付プロパティの判断処理を埋め込むのは一般的なのでしょうか...？

Comment: 特異なものでもありませんし、必要であれば使うべきかと思います。

Comment: 了解しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

DataContext がエラーを吐いているということを前提として書きます。

ちょっと試してみましたが、

```
<Window x:Class="xxx.MainWindow"
        d:DataContext="..."
        ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyDataContext/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    ...
</Window>
```

のように初期化すると DesignInstance を設定していても `MyDataContext` のコンストラクタは呼ばれるようです。

一方コードビハインドで

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyDataContext();
    }
}
```

と初期化する場合はこの部分の処理は行われませんでした。

コンストラクタではなくプロパティ経由でエラーとなっている場合は DesignInstance を設定すれば回避できます。同じプロパティを持つダミーを指定してください。

```
<Window x:Class="xxx.MainWindow"
        ...
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:FakeDataContext, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"         >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:RealDataContext/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    ...
</Window>
```

また、`Debug.Assert` ではなく単に例外を投げた場合、xamlデザイナに波線は表示されますが、ダイアログが表示されることはありません。